# Move DIV to Right form Bottom with relative to Top DIV

Tags: css, css-float

I have following Scenario

http://jsfiddle.net/EYGhf/63/

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="first_div">first div</div>
<div id="second_div">second div</div>
<div id="third_div">third div</div>    
</div>
```

I want third div to be next to first div, first and second would be in same column, if right space is not available, i.e. on mobile, third div would float to bottom.

Current CSS that is applied goes as

```
.wrapper{
widht:250px;
}
#first_div {
background: yellow;
height: 200px; /* Just Example, Actual is Dynamic*/
width:100px;
float:left;
}

#second_div {
background: cyan;
height: 300px;/* Just Example, Actual is Dynamic*/
width:100px;
clear:left;    
}
#third_div{
width:100px;
float:left;
background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `position:absolute` on 3rd item, and use media queries set it back to `static` for mobile.

**JSFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ytr1j3r7/ (resize the output frame and see)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 400px;
}
.wrapper > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
#first_div {
    background: yellow;
}
#second_div {
    background: cyan;
}
#third_div {
    background: teal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 399px) {
    #third_div {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="first_div">first div</div>
    <div id="second_div">second div</div>
    <div id="third_div">third div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually the Height of all of Divs is dynamic, so i can not add a fixed height. can we do it with widths only?

Comment: @HardCode yes, see the updated answer, it only cares about the width now, demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/ytr1j3r7/